# How to draw an image on canvas without html

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, image

I'm trying to add a sprite to the canvas of my game. However, I don't want to use an image tag. However, I haven't found a way to do this no matter how hard I searched. Something like:

```
var image = 'sample.jpg'
draw(image)
```

Comment: You've consulted the docs for [canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)?

Comment: Yes but that requires uploading the image using html, which as I said I was trying to avoid

Comment: You can create a reference to an image element in your script without that tag ever being added to your HTML document.

Comment: How? I don't really know much JavaScript.

Comment: [It's literally the first example in the docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) - just skip the "appendChild" step at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Philip's suggested improvement to DMGregory's answer is important.

```
//Create Image object
var image2 = new Image();

//Get context ready
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('mycanvasid');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

//Now, set .onload with function(s) that require a loaded image, before setting .src
image2.onload = function () {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    ctx2.drawImage(image2, x, y);  //aka, ctx2.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
}

//Finally, start the loading process
image2.src = 'path/to/your/image.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

Recapping the [doc examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) discussed in the comments above:

```
// First, create a reference to the image we want to draw.
var image = new Image(); // or document.createElement('img'); 
image.src = 'path/to/your/image.png';

// Next, find (or create/add) our canvas, and get its drawing context.
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Finally, draw our image onto the canvas with a given x & y position.
var x = 0, y = 0;
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
```

Comment: You should do the `ctx.drawImage` call in the `.onload` handler of the image. Otherwise the image will very likely be drawn before it is loaded, resulting in drawing nothing at all.